# Why is Rails generating two routes for the same resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Given the following routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'visitors#index'
  devise_for :users

  resources :users do
    resources :wishlists, :only => [:create] do
      post :action => :create, :on => :collection
      resources :items, :only => [:create, :update, :remove_item] do
        post :action => :create, :on => :collection
        put :action => :update
        delete :action => :remove_item
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Rails generates routes including the following routes which conflict:

```
              PUT    /wishlists/:wishlist_id/items/:item_id(.:format) items#update
wishlist_item PUT    /wishlists/:wishlist_id/items/:id(.:format)      items#update
```

Why does the first of these get generated? I would expect only the second one (which includes the path helper)

I'm using Rails 4.1.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your are declaring 2 times the same route:

- the first one in `resources :items, :only => [:create, :update, :remove_item]` generates this resource:  */wishlists/:wishlist_id/items/**:id**(.:format)*
- the second in `put :action => :update` generates this one: */wishlists/:wishlist_id/items/**:item_id**(.:format)*

You should be using only 1 of them (I recommend the first one).

If you want more information on routing, you should definitely go on [this page](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).